# While saving another workbook using VBA saving pop-up showing that workbook file path

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

When using VBA in master document, I need to copy & paste data from another workbook and save to that workbook. While saving saving pop-up showing file destination path but I don't want other users know the path.

[image]

```
Sub RTS()

ThisWorkbook.Activate

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ActiveSheet.Range("A7:D7", "Q7").Select ActiveSheet.Range("A7:D7,Q7").Select Range("Q7").Activate Application.CutCopyMode = False Selection.Copy

on Error Resume Next While cont Err.Clear Dim wb As Workbook Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="RTS Report.xlsx") Do Until wb.ReadOnly = False wb.Close Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01") Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="RTS Report.xlsx")

Loop

If Err.Number <> 0 Then Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")) Err.Clear Else cont = False End If

Wend

On Error GoTo 0

Dim She As Worksheet Dim b As Integer ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Activate

Set She = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

b = She.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

She.Range("A" & b + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone,

SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Cells.Select Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

ActiveWorkbook.Save ActiveWorkbook.Close ThisWorkbook.Activate Application.ScreenUpdating = True Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

put before the save string

```
Application.DisplayAlerts=False
```

and delete `"Application.DisplayAlerts = True"`